# Knockout custom validation with AJAX call issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation, knockout.js

My custom validation will validate whether or not a zip code entered into a form field is valid for a state chosen from a dropdown in the preceeding field. It works fine when I first select a state and then type in a valid/invalid zip. However, if it validates and then I go and choose a different state the validation error message does not trigger. Can anyone tell me what I am missing and why it is not re-validating?

**Custom Validation:**

```
ko.validation.rules["isValidZipCode"] =
    {
        async: true,
        getValue: function (o) {
            return (typeof o === 'function' ? o() : o);
        },
        validator: function (val, fields, callBack) {
            var self = this;
            var anyOne = ko.utils.arrayFirst(fields, function (field) {
                var val = self.getValue(field);

                if (val === undefined || val === null) 
                    return "";                
                return true;
            });

            var ajaxData = { state: anyOne, zipCode: val }
            $.ajax({
                url: $("a#ValidateZipByState").attr("href"),
                type: "POST",
                data: ajaxData,
                success: function (isValid) {
                    if (isValid) {
                        callBack(true);
                    } else {
                        callBack(false);
                    }
                },
                error: handleSubmitError
            });

            return;
        },
        message: "Invalid zip code for this state"
    };
```

**ViewModel:**

```
self.State = ko.observable(model.State).extend({ required: true });
self.ZipCode = ko.observable(model.ZipCode).extend({ required: true, pattern: /^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$/g, isValidZipCode: [self.State, self.ZipCode] });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a subscription to State and use the **ko.validation.validateObservable** method to trigger the validation on ZipCode -- also, since this validation rule is specific to ZipCode you could use an anonymous custom rule.

```
self.State = ko.observable("StateB").extend({ 
    required: true
});

self.State.subscribe(function(){
    ko.validation.validateObservable(self.ZipCode);
})

self.ZipCode = ko.observable(789).extend({
    validation: {
        async: true,
        validator: function (val, params, callback) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var zips = stateZips.get(self.State());
                var exists = zips.some(function(zip) {
                    return zip == new Number(val);
                });
                return callback(exists);
            });
        },
        message: "Invalid zip code for this state"
    }
});
```

Complete example here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RafaelCompanhoni/a4hcydjk/)

**EDIT:** In order to make State trigger the validation (without changing ZipCode first) you have to use:

```
ko.validation.init({ messagesOnModified: false });
```

Comment: Thank you Rafael. I am going to try this right now and I will let you know how it goes! i appreciate the help....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the validation rule is only attached to the ZipCode observable so updating the State value by itself would not trigger a new validation. You would have to update the state and then make another change to the zipcode before an update happens if I'm understanding the problem correctly.

If so you might want to try this quick hack to get the validation to update when the State is changed:

```
self.State.subscribe(function(newValue){
    self.ZipCode.valueHasMutated();
});
```

Comment: Thanks again Jason. I am going to try this in about 20 mins and I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: as @RafaelCompanhoni pointed out you can use ko.validation.validateObservable which is less of a hack than valueHasMutated so go with his answer. I didn't know that method existed.

Comment: So I only got back to my office this morning and first tried your hack above. It worked automagically! I am still hazy on what the valueHasMutated property is doing under the hood but I am going to try use Rafael's as well. Can you tell me wha you mean by  "instead of using the default 'val' field on your validator function"? I tried passing in the zip as an argument to the state parameter but the validation was triggering on the state field automatically. I am assuming the issue was the "val" field you mentioned above. Just not sure if you meant to remove all references to it in the function.

Comment: I was thinking you could apply the same validation rule to both observables, and so the first parameter of the validator (val) would be the value of the observable that triggered the evaluation. That's not very useful since you wouldn't know which one it was. There are some other problems with that option that I hadn't considered at first either so I'm removing it from my answer altogether.

Comment: valueHasMutated is a built in function of knockout that manually tells it the value of an observable has changed. Since I knew that knockout-validation uses that same trigger in order to trigger its validation to fire it was a way to force the validation. However that could cause some unintended side effects if you have other computed observables watching that observable so it's far safer to cut out that extra step and directly tell the validation to fire.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Jason. Now I completely understand. As a junior dev, Knockout seems to confuse me when I am doing anything more advanced than simple data-binding between viewmodel properties and the corresponding html elements. Hopefully I will get better at this but your help has been tremendous.

Comment: @DeanFriedland Happy to help! I've been using knockout for about 3 years and had a bunch of the same questions when I started. I wouldn't have been able to get far without StackOverflow so it seems only fair that I pay back some of what I've picked up.